# add extra column and retrieve data

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSL, and have the following question:

I need to create a table with the below data and add an extra column at the end:

```
<datafields>
  <field Name='name' />
  <field Name='lastname' />
  <field Name='user' />
  <field Name='text' />
</datafields>

<form>
  <comment name='Maria' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
  <comment name='Julia' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
  <comment name='Luke' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
  <comment name='Martin' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
  <comment name='Fred' lastname='jones' user='jonesm' text='hello' />
</form>
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  In your case, you are missing two key pieces of information.  (1) you have not provided a sample of what you want to output, and (2) you haven't shown that you've made an attempt to solve the problem yourself.  Please edit your post to include this.

Comment: Which of these is your input document? Or is it both? Which of these is your output document? What version of XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XML provided is a single, well-formed XML then when you take this input:

```
<root>
  <datafields>
    <field Name='name' />
    <field Name='lastname' />
    <field Name='user' />
    <field Name='text' />
  </datafields>
  <form>
    <comment name='Maria' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
    <comment name='Julia' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
    <comment name='Luke' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
    <comment name='Martin' lastname='smith' user='smithm' text='hello' />
    <comment name='Fred' lastname='jones' user='jonesm' text='hello' />
  </form>
</root>
```

And use this XSL 1.0 transform on it:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="datafields">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="field">
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
        </th>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="form">
    <xsl:for-each select="comment">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@lastname"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@user"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then it will produce this result:

```
<table>

<tr>
<th>name</th><th>lastname</th><th>user</th><th>text</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Maria</td><td>smith</td><td>smithm</td><td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Julia</td><td>smith</td><td>smithm</td><td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Luke</td><td>smith</td><td>smithm</td><td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Martin</td><td>smith</td><td>smithm</td><td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fred</td><td>jones</td><td>jonesm</td><td>hello</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

This transform will create a table header row for each item in `datafields` and a data row for each `comment` in `form`.

If you need an extra column, like you mention, you just have to add empty cells in both the second and third templates. And if it should produce a complete valid HTML page then you would need to add the appropriate tags to the first template around the `<table>` tags.